# Hide address if already completed WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I'm looking for a way to hide the billing address on the checkout page of my woocommerce theme if the user has already filled up the billing form (from a previous order or if the user has done it previously from the "my account" page).

I've found ways to hide the billing / shipping form completely on the checkout page if the user is logged in (see below), however I can't find a way to do the above.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_fields' , 'custom_override_checkout_fields' );
function custom_override_checkout_fields( $fields ) {
    if( is_user_logged_in() ){
        unset($fields['billing']);
        $fields['billing'] = array();
    }
    return $fields;
}
```

Any idea?

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It will depend what you consider to be a fully completed address i made snippet function you can use to go further with.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_fields' , 'custom_override_checkout_fields' );
function custom_override_checkout_fields( $fields ) {
    if( is_user_logged_in() && !has_billing()){
        unset($fields['billing']);
        $fields['billing'] = array();
    }
    return $fields;
}

// Check the meta of Postcode and Country if they are entered.
function has_billing($user_id = false){
            if(!$user_id)
                $user_id = get_current_user_id();

            $shipping_postcode = get_user_meta( $user_id, 'billing_postcode', true );
            $shipping_country = get_user_meta( $user_id, 'billing_country', true );

            // Fetch more meta for the condition has needed.  
            if($shipping_postcode && $shipping_country){
                return true;
            }

            return false;
}
```

Note: the prefix **shipping_** there is one for billing ( **billing_** ).

Edit: Here the meta key **billing_address_1** and **billing_address_2** always the prefix can be either **billing_** or **shipping_**

Also if for some reason you don't have a shipping or billing address associated in the user meta keys but the customer once did an order you can check this code to fetch order address.

> [Woocommerce WC_Order get_shipping_address() not returning as array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22327474/woocommerce-wc-order-get-shipping-address-not-returning-as-array)  (old post might not be valid anymore)

Comment: Thanks! I was looking for `has_billing()` instead of `!has_billing()` but otherwise it's perfect :D Thank you!!!